# Extending margin such that final entry of printbibliography fits on the page

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, geometry, chemistry, page

I have such an annoying issue. My final entry of the bibliography does not fit on the same page. I tried the following in order to increase the margin at bottom of page, but somehow the text is not affected by it:

> \lipsum
> \section{Background Literature}
> \addtolength{\textheight}{2cm}
> \printbibliography[heading=none]

[image]

Comment: you can try `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` (or similar)

Comment: Thank you!! This worked, really thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` (or a similar value). `\enlargethispage` is described in the LaTeX manual *LaTeX2e for authors* (If you have LaTeX on your computer you can find it with `texdoc usrguide`, or online here: https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/):

> ```
> \enlargethispage{<size>}
> \enlargethispage*{<size>}
> ```
>
> These commands increase the height of a page (from its normal value of
> `\textheight`) by the specified amount `<size>`, a rigid length. This
> change affects *only* the current page.
>
> This can be used, for example, to allow an extra line to be fitted
> onto the page or, with a negative length, to produce a page shorter
> than normal.
>
> The star form also shrinks any vertical white space on the page as
> much as possible, so as to fit the maximum amount of text on the page.
>
> These commands do not change the position of the footer text; thus, if
> a page is lengthened too far, the main text may overprint the footer.